# Bash Script conditional statement for directory creation - command not found error

Tags: bash, date, directory, mkdir

```
#!/bin/bash

dd=`date +%d`
mm=`date +%m`
yy=`date +%Y`
TODAY=`date +%d`
MONTH=`date +%m`
TOMORROW=`date +%d --date="1 days"`

echo $TODAY
echo $MONTH
#echo $TOMORROW


#if [ $TOMORROW < $TODAY ]; then
#   exit 0
#fi

cd /Users/name/monthly

if [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 01];
then
    mkdir -p January
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 02];
then
    mkdir -p February
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 03];
then
    mkdir -p March
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 04];
then
    mkdir -p April
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 05];
then
    mkdir -p May
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 06];
then
   mkdir -p June
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 07];
then
    mkdir -p July
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 08];
then
    mkdir -p August
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 09];
then
    mkdir -p September
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 10];
then
    mkdir -p October
elif [$TODAY == 25 && $MONTH == 11];
then
    mkdir -p November
elif [$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 12];
then
    mkdir -p December
fi
```

I am trying to create the Directory for the every Month of using shell script. 
For the testing purpose, I use date 25 for November but the conditional statement will check if the date is 01 and month is 01..12 then it will create the folder accordingly.

Today and Month is printed but for the conditional statement, I got command not found the error.

test.sh: line 21:  command not found
.....

Comment: Ypur problem is in line 21. Have you already check that line ?

Comment: Yes Line 21 is where the if statement starts @Egl

Comment: For all the statements and lines ends at 54 i got the same command not found error.

test.sh: line 21: command not found
test.sh: line 24: command not found
test.sh: line 27: command not found
test.sh: line 30: command not found
test.sh: line 33: command not found
test.sh: line 36: command not found
test.sh: line 39: command not found
test.sh: line 42: command not found
test.sh: line 45: command not found
test.sh: line 48: command not found
test.sh: line 51: command not found
test.sh: line 54: command not found

Comment: your if condition should have spaces in `[  ... ]`

Comment: @Kent I didn't get your point. Is it in every if statement there should be white space or Tab

Comment: You have to write `[ $TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 01 ]` with spaces after `[` and before `]`.

Comment: @HasanMosharrof read some tutorial of bash/shell programming, particularly the if/else part.

Comment: You may want to use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to find such errors on your own. It's a great tool. Give it a try :)

Comment: @Socowi Thanks for the link. I got the code worked and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have seen your mistake immediately, if you would not just have looked at *command not found*, but what bash printed **before** that: It outputs the command which was not found.

A conditional statement in bash has the form

```
if COMMAND
then 
   ....
```

In your case, COMMAND is something like

```
[$TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 02]
```

which is actually two commands, connected by &&. Let's assume that TODAY holds the string `05`. In this case, you would have the command

```
[05 == 01
```

which means: Call a program stored in the file named `[05`, with the parameters `==` and `01`. Since there likely is no file of this odd name in your PATH, you get *command not found*.

There are several ways to solve this, but IMO, the most readable is

```
if [[ $TODAY == 01 && $MONTH == 05 ]]
```

In this case, we have `[[` as command (and not `[05`), and since this is a syntactic element of bash instead of an external command, it does not terminate by the `&&`, but stretches up to the closing `]]`.